# Control "Program Flow" in Table View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

again me with a short question since Swift is confusing me ATM - but I hope I will get used to it soon ;)

Ok so what I was wondering is: When I call a TableView and generate different Cells is there a way to Interrupt after a few and wait for User Input and react to it? 
For Example: 2nd Cell is something like "Go to North or West" after that I want a User Input - with Buttons - in whatever direction he likes to go and react to it with following Cells (different Story Parts -> out of other Arrays?).

What is confusing me is that I just load the whole Application in viewDidLoad and i don't know how I can control the "Flow" within this.

I would really appreciate if someone could show me how I can achieve this maybe even with a small description about how I can control the Program Flow within the Method. I really think this knowledge and understanding would lift my understanding for Swift a few Levels higher.

Thanks in advance!

Here is my current Code which is not including any functionality for the named Question since I don't know how to manage this :)

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var storyLines = ["Test Cell 1 and so on first cell of many","second cell Go to North or West","third Cell - Buttons?"]
    var actualTables = 1


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return storyLines.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TxtLine", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = storyLines[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cocoa is *event driven*. You are *always* just waiting for user input. It's a matter of implementing the methods that Cocoa has configured to *tell* you about it.

So here, for example, if you want to hear about when the user presses a button, you configure the button with an action-and-target to call a method in your view controller when the user presses it. That way, your method can see which button the user pressed and remake the table view's data model (your `storyLines` array) and reload the table with the new data.

Comment: I'm still not sure how to manage this after a specific number of - in that case - cells. Also I'm not sure how to remake the Array after a Button was pressed. Either way for me it would be less confusing if I could just put any StoryLines in seperate Arrays and Call them after a Button was clicked.
Would you be so nice and show me in a short code snippet how I would be able to manage this and append new Cells below the Buttons after a Choice was made? I would really appreciate this! :)

Comment: "it would be less confusing if I could just put any StoryLines in separate Arrays and Call them after a Button was clicked" You can store your data model however you like, just as long as you are able to respond _immediately_ to the UITableViewDataSource methods such  `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAt`. The details are not crucial to my answer. What's crucial is that you respond to the button by changing the data model appropriately, whatever that means for your app, and calling `reloadData` to rebuild the table to reflect the new state of the data model.

Comment: Thank You for clarification - but with this I actually have the problem that on every reload the complete TableView reloads to the new Data Source - what I would like to achieve is that the cells from the new Data Source will append to the existing ones below - is there any way to get this result? Thank you!

Comment: But as I said a moment ago, you are the author of the data source methods. Where they get their data and how they translate that into facts about the table is totally up to you.